# Какова этимология слова "надлежащее" и история его происхождения?

Tags: этимология

Какова этимология слова "надлежащее" и история его происхождения?

Comment: Пожалуйста, используйте основную часть для подробного описания проблемы, примеров и внесения деталей.

Answer (score 3):

Интересный вопрос, спасибо!

Удалось найти только неопубликованные [записки В.В. Виноградова](http://etymolog.ruslang.ru/vinogradov.php?id=nadlegat_prinadlegat&vol=1) из "Истории слов". Приведу выдержку, но лучше ознакомиться со статьёй по ссылке.

> Глагол надлежать (надълежати) употреблялся в древнейших письменных
>   памятниках русского языка, восходящих к старославянской традиции,
>   например, у Нестора Печорского в «Житиях Феодосия». Но там значения
>   этого слова другие по сравнению с русским литературным языком XVIII —
>   XIX вв.: 1) «Лежать на чемъ...»; 2) «Угрожать: — Голицъмъ напастъмъ
>   надълежаштамъ. Изб. 1073 г.» (Срезневский, 2, с. 282). Понятно, что
>   данный глагол изменялся по формам лица и неизвестен в безличном
>   употреблении. Едва ли допустимо генетически связывать с этим глаголом
>   глагол надлежит в значении `следует, должно'.
>
> Это слово и значение в русском книжно-деловом языке развивается не
>   раньше конца XVII — начала XVII в., т. е. с ростом западноевропейских
>   влияний.
>
> Естественно рождается предположение, не появляется ли надлежит в
>   качестве калькированного слепка с латинского или немецкого слова. В
>   Лексиконе Вейсмана (1731) это слово уже отмечено и поставлено в связь
>   с латинским id tibi incumbit и немецким es liegt dir ob: «сие тебе
>   надлежит; сие твое дело, твоя должность; до тебя принадлежит» (с.
>   453).

Любопытно отметить, что в украинском языке соответствующее слово "належати" имеет похожий состав и этимологические словари говорят о его происхождении из польского "nalezyty". Этимологию в польском мне отследить не удалось.

Answer (score 1):

По некоторым иследованиям (В. Топоров, Исследования по этимологии и семантике. Том 1.), одним из значений глагола "надлежать" (помимо притяжательности в диалектном употреблении) было *"лежать в каком-либо направлении" (Куды идёшь, человече, куды путь твоя **надлежит**?)*. https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=lZ3SAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA180&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U0N-cMBCfkolUhSkHgE7GgPh_kgwA&w=1280

Отсюда могло возникнуть переносное значение предначертанности *пути* и следования ему (при дальнейшем абстрагировании - *действия* ожидаемым, должным образом).